# The best way to develope dependet form fields with PHP/JS

Tags: javascript, php

I am looking for best nice, easy and fast solution for dependent fields in form.

Eg. When I choose Car A in next select list (or any other form filed) I want to see Type A or B, when I choose Car B in next select list I want to see Type C or D. (Not A, B, C, D together in second list in two cases).

I implement case with JS to automatically send form after select item in first list, and process selected value with PHP to display correct select list after page load.

I also implement this case with PHP and divide the process to few steps. And I store the values selected in previous rows in session.

What is the best way to solve this problem, is storing values in session a good practise, meaby I should use get ?

Answer (score 1):

The best way (for me) is to send ajax request on select value in first list, and after ajax-response just put the answert in second list
(php script must restore options tags for your list)

Ex. (with JQuery)

HTML

```
<select id="A" >
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
<select id="B" ></select>
```

JS

```
$('#A').change(function(){
   var value = $(this).val();
   $.post('/path/to/ajax.php',{aValue:value}, function(optionsHtml){
       $('#B').html(optionsHtml);
   },'html')
});
```

PHP

```
<?php 
$values = [
   1=>['L1','L2'], 
   2=>['L3','L4']
];
foreach($values[$_POST['aValue']] as $l){
    echo '<option value="'.$l.'">'.$l.'</option>';
}
```